# T4MVC through CDN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I want to move my static content to CDN. But I like (love?) T4MVC and want to keep using it. So ideally I want to just replace in production "http://mysite" to "http://cdnaddress/path". Did somebody try it? Could there be any pitfalls?

Comment: t4mvc has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Daniel, really? T4MVC generates my "strongly-typed" static links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for ProcessVirtualPathDefault in T4MVC.tt.settings.t4:

```
// You can change the ProcessVirtualPath method to modify the path that gets returned to the client.
// e.g. you can prepend a domain, or append a query string:
//      return "http://localhost" + path + "?foo=bar";
private static string ProcessVirtualPathDefault(string virtualPath) {
    // The path that comes in starts with ~/ and must first be made absolute
    string path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(virtualPath);

    // Add your own modifications here before returning the path
    return path;
}
```

You should be able to achieve what you want by tweaking this code.